# Require Date and Time in MS Access Textbox

Tags: ms-access, datetime, ms-access-2007

How can I enforce that an entered `Date/Time` value in a bound textbox contains both the date component and the time component (in other words a full timestamp)?

**Update** (for clarification): The column is a user-entered timestamp, so a missing date or a missing time would not make sense.

Comment: If you're using the current date and time you could just disable the field and manually code `=Now()`.  Either that or use a validation rule.

Comment: What is the data type of the field which is the text box's control source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do this then you could create an Input Mask using, for example:

```
00/00/0000\ 00:00:00;0;_
```

As soon as they start typing it will insist on all digits being entered. Then can still press Esc to abandon the field-editing.

I am not a huge fan of Input Masks - particularly for dates as it forces the user to use a format that they might be less comfortable with.

Be careful when using Input Masks if you also use the Format property; if they don't match it can be troublesome.

I also suggest that if you have different forms for this data-entry then use the same mask consistently.

Comment: +1 And I agree about masks.  Without a mask, I can enter `7-29-13 3p` in a Date/Time text box, and Access recognizes it correctly.  Masks are less flexible.

Comment: The Input Mask seems to be a simple (but discouraged) way to enforce a full timestamp (date and time).  Can you recommend any alternatives?

Comment: I think it is the best solution. You could write some intricate code using events `Change`, `KeyUp` etc., but if you want to insist on full data-entry for the date/time then use an Input Mask.

Answer (score 2):

The text box is bound to a Date/Time field.  Date/Time values *always* include both date and time components.  If the user does not supply a date component, the date will be day 0 (Dec. 30 1899).  If the user does not supply a time component, the time will be midnight (00:00:00).

If Dec. 30 1899 is outside the range of date values you need to accommodate, it would be easy to require the user input a (non-zero) date.

See whether this Immediate window session helps clarify the situation.

```vb
? #07:00#
7:00:00 AM 
? Format(#07:00#, "yyyy-m-d hh:nn:ss")
1899-12-30 07:00:00
? DateValue(#07:00#) = CDate(0)
True
```

You could use the text box's before update event to check `DateValue(Me.TextBoxName) = CDate(0)`  If that expression is `True`, display a notice to the user and `Cancel` the update.

For the time requirement ...

```vb
? #2013-7-31#
7/31/2013 
? Format(#2013-7-31#, "yyyy-m-d hh:nn:ss")
2013-7-31 00:00:00
? TimeValue(#2013-7-31#) = CDate(0)
True
```

The logic is similar to the date piece, with the complication that midnight could be an acceptable time value.  If that is so, I don't see how you can distinguish between the user entering midnight vs. midnight as a result of no time value entered.  Perhaps the best bet would be to ask the user to confirm midnight times.